# Golang cannot import a forked repository

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm extending an existing database driver (https://github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB-Go).

I use the github url as an import in my `main.go`, and in the `go.mod`:

`replace github.com/fajran/go-monetdb@latest => github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB-Go v1.0.0`

Yet when I try to `go get`/`go install`/`go run` it, it says:

```
main.go:7:2: no required module provides package github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB-Go; to add it:
    go get github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB-Go
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it because it's a fork?

Comment: In general you **cannot** get a "Github fork" of a Go package to compile and run properly. Only trivial cases work (by using replace).

Comment: You're changed the module name to your fork, the old package was not part of a module, and there is only one package within the module. What are you trying to do with `replace` here? You should be able to just import `github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB-Go/src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to replace anything, since you already import `github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB-Go`.

Your error comes from the fact that the source code in `github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB-Go` is under the `src` directory.

---

Final `go.mod` file:

```
module example

go 1.16

require github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB-Go v1.0.0
```

Final `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB-Go/src"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(monetdb.MAPI_STATE_INIT) // prints 0
}
```